# How can do all these two functions at the same time (bash, pipe)

Tags: bash, shell, logging, pipe, xcodebuild

I'm trying to do all these two functions at the same time,

```
xcodebuild || exit
```

and,

```
xcodebuild | tee xcodebuild.log | xcpretty
```

in a script file,

```
build.sh
```

Now I do it like this, but the last command 'exit' not work.

```
xcodebuild | tee xcodebuild.log | xcpretty || exit
```

I expect the command 'xcodebuild', not only can print logs to a file, but also can 'exit' my script file when it error.

If anyone could give me a hint in the right direction as to how should I do it would really be appreciated.

**Updated** *It works for me:*

```
xcodebuild | tee xcodebuild.log | xcpretty
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" != "0" ]; then
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| - is pipe, so the output on the LHS becomes input of the RHS (LHS= left hand side of the symbol)

; - next command will run regardless of the exit status of the previous command

&& - means RHS command will execute ONLY if LHS has exit status of 0, which means success

|| - is the opposite of directly above

These above are all serial commands.

Paralell run is done with mpi, or at least threads

exit was not exiting because xcpretty was returning SUCCESS, even though you wanted to hang the condition to xcodebuild

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirement correctly, you can send one to the background to keep it running in a subshell there, and keep the other one in the foreground (depending on our need you can send this one to background too):

```
{ xcodebuild || exit ;} & xcodebuild | tee xcodebuild.log | xcpretty
```

Or you can use a real multi-processing tool like GNU `parallel`.